# WPF: Partial data binding in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textblock

So here is my `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="1 Projects / 1 Issues"></TextBlock>
```

Using data binding I want replace 1 and 2 with `{Binding Path=OpenProjects}` and `{Binding Path=OpenIssues}`. What is the best way to do this?

P.S. I am not married to `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Projects / {1} Issues">
      <Binding Path="OpenProjects"/>
      <Binding Path="OpenIssues"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [string format](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx)